# Landlord Tax Relief Changes UK

Tags: taxes, income-tax, landlord

I understand that the tax relief for landlords in the U.K. will be affected by the mortgage not being able to offset as an expense of doing business.

**My question is, can anyone provide an example of how this will change the profitability of the landlord from pre-to post tax changes?**

I am struggling to understand how this has a practical effect

Many thanks for your assistance

David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This article](https://www.property118.com/similar-tax-similar-incomes/95315/) on the landlord website Property118.com shows a simple example, demonstrating that a private landlord with a mortgage could see a huge jump in their effective tax rate (in this case, from 18% to 67% by 2020), while a corporate landlord will see no change at all.

There's also a [link in that article](https://media.property118.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/6G0YKMd1Wf.pdf) to a detailed report which is highly critical of the tax changes. [The government obviously take a different view](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/restricting-finance-cost-relief-for-individual-landlords/restricting-finance-cost-relief-for-individual-landlords)! ([See here](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/changes-to-tax-relief-for-residential-landlords-how-its-worked-out-including-case-studies) for more worked examples of how the tax changes will be applied).

More information can be found on this on various landlord sites. A key phrase to look for is "[section 24](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2015/33/section/24/enacted)", referring to the section of the Finance (No. 2) Act 2015 which implements the change.

Note that this change only applies to private landlords (i.e. those who own a property personally, rather than through a company), and who have a mortgage on the property, and who (after the new calculations) are higher or additional rate taxpayers.